# "Cannot find module '@angular/cli/plugins/webpack'"

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I tried upgrading my project from Angular 4 to Angular 6 and ran into some issues with webpack. I am getting the error "Cannot find module '@angular/cli/plugins/webpack'"

Upon looking for the module.the cli folder now doesn't have a webpack.js file which was there before updating the cli version

I updated angular CLI from 1.4.1 to 6.2.9

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing this dependency from my webpack file:
`require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');`

The scripts that we were using are now default in the `angular.json` configuration file in Angular6+